# I want to know how to Remove duplicates on a single column in excel USING PYTHON

Tags: python, excel, automation

I am just a beginner and am working on to automate excel file using python. Can someone pleaseee tell the code on how to remove duplicates from single column in excel using python.

Also I want to know if its possible to run macros in excel from python, and if so, will the automation of excel be easier using python?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary that you show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you ([No attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)). Reading [Ask] might help you to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

> Also I want to know if its possible to run macros in excel from python

Yes, use [RemoveDuplicates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.removeduplicates):

```
Sub RemoveDupsEx1()
//Check column A,B,C and remove dulipates.
Range("A1:C8").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3), Header:=xlYes
End Sub
```

**Note**:
[Header] – Does data have a header? xlNo (default), xlYes, xlYesNoGuess

Comment: In header, should i need to include the name of the column whose duplicates to be removed? for eg i have to remove from column B ?

Comment: If you want to remove from column B, use Columns:=2
(because B is the second column)